# What's wrong with my infinite series expansion for $\log(x)$?

Tags: logarithms, power-series

Here, log is natural log.

Looking at $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, I tried to put $f(x)$ in the form $\frac{a}{1-r}$ that an infinite geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a \cdot r^n)$ converges to when $\mid r \mid < 1$.

That gave me $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-(1-x)}$, so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^n$ should converge to $\frac{1}{x}$ for $0<x<2$.

Now, taking the anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ gives me $\log(x) + C$, and anti-differentiating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^n$ should give me a power series expansion for $\log(x)$, no?

But I end up with $$\int 1 + (1-x) + (1-x)^2 + ...dx$$

$$= x + x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + x - x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3-...+C$$

And this doesn't look right.

Comment: You want a power series expansion in $(1-x)$ or $x-1$ if you're going to do this. The usual Taylor expansion that people see is for $\log(1-x)$, and then you get a series converging for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Why did you expand everything? Leave $\int (1 - x)^2 \, dx$ as $-\frac{(1 - x)^3}{3}$.

Comment: The first series is only defined for $0<x<2$, so you can't get a Taylor series centered at $0$.

Comment: @Farnight while you're right, the question doesn't ask to find a Taylor series rather just clarifying details with the expansion the OP found, no?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29, He's trying to expand the terms to get a series of the form $\sum a_n x^n$. Isn't that the same thing as a power series centered at $0$?

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, you are right. He was trying to rearrange the terms into a power series expansion at $0$, and that cannot be done. I thought he was just trying to find some series expansion of $\log x$ after using the power series representation of $1/x$. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is from expanding all the terms in parentheses; while it's not wrong, it's obfuscating the point, which is to end up with an expression involving powers of $x - 1$.

So don't expand. Get

$$C + x - \frac{(1 - x)^2}{2} - \frac{(1 - x)^3}{3} - ...$$

I'll leave it to you to check that $C = -1$, so the series is

$$- \left((1 - x) + \frac{(1 - x)^2}{2} + \frac{(1 - x)^3}{3} + \dots\right)$$

After rearranging, this is

$$(x - 1) - \frac{(x - 1)^2}{2} + \frac{(x - 1)^3}{3} - \dots$$

as desired.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now, I have to work on my algebra a little more.